# batch - run command series on new window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First thing fist, this is the first attempt with batch.

I am writing a small utility script that executes very simple tasks, and I have already pretty much everything in place.

What I want to do is execute some of the actions in a different command window.

I managed to get a new window to open, but the problem I've got is that it exectues the first command only, and the second one still runs on the first window.

Here's some code:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO  1  - tail - Error
ECHO  2  - tail - Access
ECHO -----------------------------
ECHO  X  - Close
SET /P M=Select the action number then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1  GOTO error
IF %M%==2  GOTO access
IF %M%==X GOTO EOF


:error
ECHO.
start cmd /K ssh web 
sleep 5
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
GOTO MENU

:access
ECHO.
start cmd /K ssh web
sleep 5
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
GOTO MENU
```

with this code, the new window opens and the ssh command runs. It waits 5 seconds and then it tries to tail the first window (the one with the menu) and not the newly opened ssh window.

How do I change this? any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `tail`? it is not a native Windows command prompt utility; perhaps there is a suitable tag which you should add to your question then...

Comment: I am using this on vagrant...it will ssh into the vegrantbox and then run tail
the command is not the issue as it works if i type it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the command **start cmd /K ssh web** the control is passed straight back to your menu script. *(your sleep command, which BTW isn't a default command within cmd, is also run on the menu script)*

You may need to either try concatenating your commands using **&** or instead call another script.

*concatenation example:*

```bat
@ECHO OFF
CLS

:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO  1  - tail - Error
ECHO  2  - tail - Access
ECHO -----------------------------
ECHO  X  - Close

CHOICE /C 12X /N /M "Select the action number."

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO :EOF
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 CALL :ACTION access
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :ACTION error
GOTO :EOF

:ACTION
ECHO.
START "" /WAIT CMD /C "ssh web & sleep 5 & tail -f /var/log/apache2/%1.log"
GOTO :MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give all the commands to the new window:

```
start cmd /K "ping google.de & timeout 5"
```

`&` is to run one command after the other. See [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for some more useful options: `&&`, `||`)

(I used commands, that work on my computer to show the principle)

Note: `cmd /k` will keep the window open. Use `cmd /c` if you want it to close when finished.

Comment: If I run this from the command line I just get the error  "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"

Comment: @Luke: do you run it within a PowerShell console? Batch is meant to run in a `cmd` console.